# Conversion error in std::remove function

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++

Hello im trying to import a code a guy made in visual studio with c++ to gcc in linux. Im getting an error at this piece of code at the rhs.erase line.

```
void cleanString(std::string &rhs) {
    char chars[] = "/-";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(chars); ++i){
        rhs.erase(std::remove(rhs.begin(), rhs.begin()+3, chars[i]), rhs.begin()+3);
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
../src/ApplicationMethods.cpp: In function ‘void RetrievalUtil::ApplicationMethods::cleanString(std::string&)’:
../src/ApplicationMethods.cpp:27:61: error: cannot convert ‘std::basic_string<char>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int remove(const char*)’
   rhs.erase(std::remove(rhs.begin(), rhs.begin()+3, chars[i]), rhs.begin()+3);
```

Im not an expert on c++ and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need `#include <algorithm>`. Otherwise you will not get the `std::remove` you want, and instead pick up the function from `stdio.h` that deletes a file (and expects a `const char*` argument).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, #include <algorithm> made it work!

Comment: @Brian, even with `std::remove` it still gets the `stdio.h` version? Or from `<cstdio>`? This seems extremely odd, especially if you happen to include both `<algorithm>` and `<cstdio>`.

Comment: @vsoftco My bad, I should have said `<cstdio>`. `<cstdio>` must declare its functions in the `std` namespace.